# Prevent delegates (not events) from causing memory leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, delegates

What's best practice for preventing delegates from causing memory leaks? For event handlers I would just call -= for each registered handler. I have my delegate assigned with a '=' (equals sign). Shall I just assign NULL at dispose time?

```
public delegate int MyDelegate(string message);

public class MyManager MyDelegate 
{   
    public MyDelegate ManagerDelegate;

..


public class Transaction
{
    public int DoSomething(string message)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public void init()
    {
        var manager = new MyManager();
        manager.ManagerDelegate = this.DoSomething("abc");
```

Comment: Assigned to *what*? To events, or to delegate-typed variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance delegate references a class instance (in its [`Target`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property), so if you store that delegate somewhere, whether an event or a simple delegate typed property, that will reference your original class. In this respect, it doesn't matter if it's an event or not. So if you want to have your original class garbage collected while the other class stays alive, you have to clean up. Remove your event handlers and also any other delegates. If the other class dies first, your original class can die, too, so it depends on your specific case.

Update: proof: http://pastebin.com/XcTz76dY

Comment: "Remove ... also any other delegates" by assigning NULL, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. It works the same way as events. IMHO you should use events only though, it seems like a better design.

Comment: Agreed, the delegate property is not my code though.